# Bootstrap Pagination first page loading delay

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm developing a website in php and I'm using one of the free bootstrap templates which includes a pagination modules in javascript, here the link:
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

The problem is that when I loop the results in PHP from the DB, the web page is displaying all the results(~2000) in a very long long list and once loaded, it then split them in pages and display just the first 10 as it should.

This is happening every time I visit/refresh the page

Is there any way I can workaround this without changing the pagination completely?

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your PHP code, but it doesn't seem like this is a problem with the theme - if your PHP fetches all 2000 results, your best bet for pagination is to only retrieve a small number of results from the database and then display those.

Comment: Since SB Admin 2 uses DataTables jQuery plugin, [this](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) might work for you. Server side processing means that only a portion of records is returned when you make your request (for example, load the page for the first time). And everytime you click on a different page, another request is sent to the server. Open up the document inspector in your browser, and click on the Networking tab, with only XHR checked. Then, click on any of the pages listed under the table, and you'll see that a new request is being sent with every pageclick.